# Customize chapter template - black left page and white right page

Tags: chapters, books

I'm in the process of making a book and came over a customized chapter template I would like to use, both don't know how to set it up in overleaf. So I want the left page to be pagecolor black with white text of the chapter heading. Then the right page to be pagecolor white with chapter number in black text together with the quote. [image]
These are my settings:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}
    \geometry{showframe=false}
    \geometry{margin=0.5in,bottom=0.70in, top=0.80in, bindingoffset=0.2in}
    \usepackage[super,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{WHAT IS LIFE?}

\begin{quote}
  \textit{``Life teaches you a new lesson every day if you are attentive enough in the class of life.''}
  \begin{center}
    {\textbf{\textit{--- Invajy}}}
  \end{center}
\end{quote} 

\lipsum[21-40]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class like `scrbook` this can be done using option `open=left` to start new chapters on a left page and redefining `\chapterlinesformat` or `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. Here we go:

```
\documentclass[open=left,chapterprefix,footsepline]{scrbook}% 11pt and twoside are defaults
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=false}% you could move this to the options of \usepackage above
\geometry{margin=0.5in,bottom=0.70in, top=0.80in, bindingoffset=0.2in}% you could move this to the options of \usepackage above
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{lmodern}% you should use as scalable font like this one
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\let\MakeMarkcase\MakeUppercase% Use uppercase in page header
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{% redefine output of chapter heading
  \pagecolor{black}% use black background
  #3% output the title
  \clearpage
  \nopagecolor% deactivate background
  \raggedleft #2% output the number
}

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\color{gray!50}\fontsize{64}{72}\selectfont}% color and fontsize of number
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{white}\fontsize{64}{72}\selectfont}% color and fontsize of title
\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{\thechapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{WHAT IS LIFE?}

\begin{quote}
  \textit{``Life teaches you a new lesson every day if you are attentive enough in the class of life.''}
  \begin{center}
    {\textbf{\textit{--- Invajy}}}
  \end{center}
\end{quote} 

\lipsum[21-40]

\end{document}
```

[image: double page with chapter title on left page with black background and number on right page]

With KOMA-Scrip I would also suggest to set the quote using `\setchapterpreamble`. And adding `\MakeUppercase` to the output of the chapter title would print automatic chapter titles like title of the table of contents also in uppercase:

```
\documentclass[open=left,chapterprefix,footsepline]{scrbook}% 11pt and twoside are defaults
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=false}% you could move this to the options of \usepackage above
\geometry{margin=0.5in,bottom=0.70in, top=0.80in, bindingoffset=0.2in}% you could move this to the options of \usepackage above
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{lmodern}% you should use as scalable font like this one
\usepackage{mwe} % for dummy text

\let\MakeMarkcase\MakeUppercase% Use uppercase in page header
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{% redefine output of chapter heading
  \pagecolor{black}% use black background
  \MakeUppercase{#3}% output the title with automatic upper case added for titles like CONTENTS
  \clearpage
  \nopagecolor% deactivate background
  \raggedleft #2% output the number
}

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\color{gray!50}\fontsize{64}{72}\selectfont}% color and fontsize of number
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{white}\fontsize{52}{64}\selectfont}% color and fontsize of title
\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{\thechapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setchapterpreamble{%
\begin{quote}
  \textit{``Life teaches you a new lesson every day if you are attentive enough in the class of life.''}
  \begin{center}
    {\textbf{\textit{--- Invajy}}}
  \end{center}
\end{quote}
}

\chapter{WHAT IS LIFE?}

\lipsum[21-40]

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image: improved version with table of contents]

Additional changes like using KOMA-Script command `\lipsum` or package `csquotes` for the quote or adding `\thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}` after the `\clearpage` in the `\chapterlinesformat` definition or using package `scrlayer-scrpage` to extend the foot separation line and change the color of that line etc. could be useful. This depends mainly on the desired result and your own taste.